# Does an API with a rate limit need to provide requests remaining?

Tags: united-kingdom, is-x-legal

I'm writing code to make requests from a public API. They give me an API key, and the API provides 1000 requests per day for free, and a max of 60 per minute. In the event that I pass one of those limits, I will be liable for a fee. I don't have to enter my payment details to use the API.

This all seems fine. However, there is no count of how many requests I've used on a given day on the website or on my account page, nor in the API's response (in the response header or data). So, given a line of code that calls the API, there is no way for me to know whether running it will cost me money. When I ask the company, they say it's up to me to add a counter and keep track. So unless all my applications/environments tell each other how many requests I've used, then I have no means of tracking how many I have remaining. In addition, I don't know what time the count resets each day, or each minute. So even if I keep track and only have one application that uses the API, there's no way for me to know if my count equals their count because I don't know when they reset it.

The only thing they'll tell me is when I owe them money by going over the limit. Is this okay, or is there some legal expectation that they tell me when a request will cost me money, such as returning a count of requests remaining this day/minute?

The company's headquarters is in the UK, but the API is used worldwide.

**Edit:** After some further looking at the company's website and documentation, and comparing to what it used to say using Archive.org, I've determined that it will probably not incur charges if I reach a limit, but further requests will instead return HTTP 429 (the code for "rate limit exceeded"), which seems much more reasonable.

Comment: What makes you think there is a requirement for them to give you that information?

Comment: @DJClayworth Because when I go to a store, the store has to tell me the price of something I want to take. Upon choosing a basket of fruit, I know exactly what the cost will be, because they weigh it and then tell me, prior to my paying and walking out the door. This company is telling me to take some free and walk out the door, and then if I take more than a certain amount, they'll come after me.

Comment: What does API stand for?

Comment: @ohwilleke Application Programming Interface. In this case, it's a website URL that you can access to get data you want from someone's website.

Answer (score 4):

You could establish your own server which calls the API and maintains a counter, and have al your applications call that server, the server call the API, and the server can also return a count to the application, or  even return a failure code if the count is too high.

As for when the count turns over, a few days experiment should establish that, but given that the API is based in the EU, I would guess it turns over at midnight UTC (aka Greenwich mean time), but of course that is only a guess.

Has the API management declined even to tell when the count rolls over?  That seems odd.

As to the legal obligations of the API management, it would be good practice for them to  have the API return a count, but I don't see that they can be required to do that. I don't know of (and could not find) any law which mandates such a count. I do think that they should inform you of the time of day at which they roll the count over. I have not yet found a law which specifically requires this.

Comment: They responded that it's UTC.

Comment: @mbomb007
 Then you can implement your own count by any of several techniques.

Comment: Still, it's really easy for them to add the count remaining in a response header, assuming they're tracking the number already, which they have to in order to charge people. It's much harder for every customer to implement their own solution.

Comment: @mbomb007 Yes, but they are under no **legal** obligation to make that improvement. You could switch to a  better API, if one weas available. And note they may not be maintaining a live count for each customer. Perhaps they just log a timestamp and customer ID for each API call, and total them up while running a billing process once a day or even once a month. Anyway, you can control your costs if you take the trouble to implement your own counter.

Comment: @mbobb007, it's easy for you to count the calls as well.

Answer (score 0):

No, they don't have to give you the count, count your requests yourself.

Comment: While i suspect you re correct, as my answer shows, did you find any law that says this, or any legal authority for this position? You cite none, and do not say what research you did.

Comment: @DavidSiegel why would there be a law?  It's just a user agreement.

Comment: Because this is LAW.se, and the OP asked  " is there some **legal** expectation" that the API return a count, or otherwise signal before a charge is incurred.